# how to use xml with style tags using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, xml, plugins

I am working in an angularjs application, i need to parse xml file in my app, which contains HTML style attributes in to it.
Have use xml2json and X2JS pluging to convert the data, while using the plugin it convert all data into json including the HTML styles.
If anyone face this issue please suggest some idea to rectifiy my problem.
Any help would be thankful.

Here is the sample code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<test>
<datas>
<data>This is my sample <b> xml </b> file</data>
<data>This is the second line of the <p style="text-align:justify">content</p></data>
<data>This is <span style="font-size: 12px"> third line </span></data>
</datas>
</test>
```

Comment: What is the purpose - templates in directives?

Comment: Actually it is an magazine application, the content we need to shown will be in the format of xml.